# Mint tokens using plutus scripts with the serialization lib

Tags: plutus, nft, minting, token, cardano-serialization-lib

As I understand, in order to mint a token with the serialization-lib, you must use the function `set_mint_scripts`, providing a `NativeScripts` object. This collection of `NativeScript` objects should determine until what time a token can be minted and by whom.

With the introduction of Plutus, though, we have a new way of minting assets, which is using Plutus scripts. They allow or not the minting and burning of the assets based on arbitrary logic. These scripts are defined in the serialization-lib as `PlutusScript` and there doesn't seem to be a way of converting a plutus script into a native one (which makes sense since they are different things).

Is my understanding correct? And, if so, did I miss any function or object that is actually able to do what I want? If not, are there any workarounds I could make use of?

Comment: Im having the same question, did you found something about this?